# Разбить строку на цифры + спецсимволы и буквы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регулярным выражением.  Нужно из строки с цифрами, буквами и спец символами получить отдельно цифры + спецсимволы + буквы.
Моя попытка

```
var chars = str.slice(0, str.search(/[a-zA-Z]+/));
var numbs = str.replace(chars, '');
```

В результате если нет букв, то в буквы записывается символ из строки.
Желаемый результат получить две переменные в первой все до 1 буквы, в остальной все после первой буквы

Answer (score 0):

Ну например вот так. Просто каждому совпадению даёшь группу, если в первых 2 не попало, то . забирает остальное.  А оператор (?:  ) говорит что эту группу не учитывать...

```js
let s = "ccJIvd(X49YkZyDdm)eI(*Sf+^ngZtpw"
let ok = s.matchAll(/(?:([A-Z])|([0-9])|(.))/ig)

let tokens = [...ok].map(function(token) {
   let [match, is_char, is_number, is_token] = token;
   if ( is_char ) return [match, 'char', token.index];
   if ( is_number ) return [match, 'number', token.index];
   if ( is_token ) return [match, 'token', token.index];
})

console.log(tokens)
```

**Добавлено спустя, читаем комментарии**

```js
let s = "123><?321абв123123";
let ok = s.matchAll(/(?:([A-ZА-Я])|([0-9])|(.))/ig);

let {first, second} = [...ok].map(function(token) {
   let [match, is_char, is_number, is_token] = token;
   if ( is_char ) return [match, 'char', token.index];
   if ( is_number ) return [match, 'number', token.index];
   if ( is_token ) return [match, 'token', token.index];
}).reduce(function(collection, [match, type]) {
if (collection.is_letter_found) {
    collection.second += match;
} else if (type === "char") {
    collection.is_letter_found = true;
    collection.second += match;
} else {
    collection.first += match;
}
return collection;
}, {is_letter_found: false, first: "", second: ""});

console.log(first, second);  // 123><?321  абв123123
```

Comment: Не думаю, что `js` правильное название для языка будет, но похоже как-то прокатывало)

Comment: возможно я не полностью описал вопрос. Строка всегда начинается с цифр, потом могут идти спец символы, цифры, и потом буквы. пример '123><?321абв123123' на выходе получить две строки '123><?321'  и 'абв123123'

Comment: А что мешает использовать на tokens редюсер и уже разбить всё как тебе в идеале нужно? Я всё равно не до конца понимаю, то-есть в первую строку должен попасть цифры+токены, во вторую всё что начинается с буквы?  Параметры редюсера могут быть такими `{is_letter_found: false, first: "", second: ""}` заполняешь первую строку пока не найдёшь первое совпадение по 'char', потом меняешь is_letter_found на истину, и заполняешь вторую строку. Если ты используешь русские буквы - то соответственно совпадения по char должны быть `[A-ZА-Я]`

Comment: я думал это можно сделать без функций, map и т.д. только на регулярке

Comment: @zxcqwe Конечно можно. Но зачем? Регулярки по своей сущности коробка с лагами, и если есть возможность как-то их поменьше расписывать (не создавать сложные выражения), то лучше поменьше их расписывать. В твоем примере я бы вообще отказался от регулярки, и решил задачу рез обычный split.reduce. Операции map и reduce в этом плане намного быстрее работают и решают ту-же задачу.

Comment: @zxcqwe Я почему-то сначала подумал что тебе этот код нужен что-бы посчитать количество букв, цифр, знаков в пароле. Как правило такой замысловатый код для этого и используется.